# Install Tidal App

Tags: software-installation, snap

I installed Tidal via the instructions here
https://snapcraft.io/install/tidal/ubuntu

I used the terminal and entered the commands. it was successfully installed.

One note, when I rebooted there was some kind of error message.

Tidal does not show up on the list of applications. I tried to rerun the install but it says it is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Tidal Tools is a native snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it search for tidal in Ubuntu Software or install it from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo snap install tidal
```

Either log out and back in again, or restart your system, to ensure snap’s paths are updated correctly. To start Tidal Tools type the following command in the terminal:

```
snap run tidal
```

The tidal snap package will be updated in the background whenever updates become available.

Answer (score 0):

The [official site](https://tidalmigrations.com/tidal-tools/) shows some screenshots of console windows.

So after installation you will be able to use `tidal` command in terminal. Also you can read [the documentation](https://guides.tidalmg.com/tidal-tools.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Download latest tidal from its site [here](https://get.tidal.sh/).

You can install tidal using following commands in terminal.

Unzip tarball file in location you downloaded file.

```
tar xvf tidal-linux-<platform>-v<version_number>.tar.gz
```

Copy standalone binary to /usr/bin

```
sudo cp tidal /usr/bin/
```

Try `tidal` command in terminal, it should work.

**Alternate way**: You can run following command which will run bash script and install latest available version of tidal command line.

```
curl https://get.tidal.sh/unix | bash
```